# Dictionary comprehension multiple ways

Tags: python, generator, python-internals

What would be the difference between the following two statements in python?

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
a = {item:0 for item in l}
b = dict((item,0) for item in l)
a == b
# True
```

I believe the first is the proper way to initialize a dictionary via comprehension from [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), yet the second way seems to just create a generator expression and then create a dict from that (and so maybe it does the exact same thing as the first approach behind the scenes?). What actually would be the difference between the two, and which one should be preferred over the other?

Comment: You've described exactly the difference, the first builds a dictionary using a dict-comprehension directly (essentially sugar for a loop: `result = {}; for item in l: result[item] = 0`. The other creates a generator expression and passes that to the `dict` constructor... The most straightforward way would be to use the former approach.

Comment: The only differences are going to be really technical ones, like the fact that the first one works if you reassign the name `dict` to be something else. Also, the first one is probably a little more efficient.

Comment: Semantically, if we assume no built-in names have been shadowed, then the two are the same, and have the same time/space complexity, although, the generator expression will probably be slightly slower because it adds the unnecessary layer of iterating over a generator expression instead of directly over a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = {item:0 for item in l}
```

Directly constructs a `dict`, no intermediates.

```
b = dict((item,0) for item in l)
```

Generates a tuple for each item in the list and feeds that to the `dict()` constructor.

Without really digging into the guts of the resulting Python byte code, I doubt there's an easy way of finding out how exactly they differ. Performance-wise, they are likely to be very close as well.

The main thing here I would consider is readability and maintainability. The first way only relies on the elements you need, without involving an intermediate data type (tuple) and without directly calling a type, but instead relying on the language itself to hook things up correctly. As a bonus, it's shorter and simpler - I don't see any advantage in using the second option, except maybe for the explicit use of `dict`, telling others what the expected type is. But if they don't get that from the `{}` in the first instance, I doubt they're much good anyway...

I figured I'd test the speed:

```
from timeit import timeit
from random import randint

l = [randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(1000)]


def first():
    return {item: 0 for item in l}


def second():
    return dict((item,0) for item in l)


print(timeit(first, number=10000))
print(timeit(second, number=10000))
```

Result:

```
0.46899440000000003
1.0817516999999999
```

Consistently faster as well, so no need to ever use the second option, it seems. If there's anything surprising here, it's actually how poorly optimised the second example is and how badly it performs.